# Who else makes H-bar Loop Handlebars?

Tags: parts, touring, handlebars

[Jones](http://www.jonesbikes.com/) makes a great pair of [touring handlebars](http://www.jonesbikes.com/handlebars/) with a loop for mounting lots of accessories, but their prices are a bit steep ($120-$425). I'm building a mountain touring bike and I've been trying to find a comparable bar for a more reasonable price, but so far no luck.

Is Jones the only company that makes this style of handlebar?

[image: Jones h-bar loop handlebar]

---

Note: There are plenty of accessory mounts that can do the same job as the loop on the h-bar, but I'm not interested in those. I'm looking for this exact style of bar, or a significantly similar bar.

Comment: I work with an engineer who fashion his own bolt on version for lights on his drop bars. His bar has a computer on it but below that he has a second bar with a light and spare mounted. I saw it and thought it was a good solution.

Comment: @DWGKNZ any chance of a picture?  I need to make something like this as my new front light sits lower than the old one and shines on the brake/gear cables when properly adjusted.

Comment: @ChrisH - You might be interested in looking at a [Nitto Lamp Holder](https://www.google.ca/search?q=Nitto+Lamp+Holders&safe=off&espv=2&biw=1229&bih=1018&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ei=ryxqVMvhFMieoQSKkILQBA&ved=0CAYQ_AUoAQ)

Comment: Not related, but you may find an alternative here: http://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/1195/different-kinds-of-handlebars/8847#8847

Comment: @Jahaziel I actually have a couple of those bars, that's why I'm surprised that Jones seems to own the market with this bar, it's basically just a Moustache bar with a cross-section. It's not a super complicated design.

Comment: Indeed, @ShemSeger. I guess there must be some kind of patent issue combined with low demand. That is why I suggest getting a couple mid-priced aluminum moustache handlebar and getting them to a shop capable of welding a piece of one into the other.

Comment: How and where do you mount your shifters/hoods to this piece of equipment?

Comment: Most of the comments here are from 2015. Now, in 2018, you can get loop bars just like these on Alibaba. They don't sell them openly, but if you ask, you'll be able to order one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is **NOBODY**. Jones is the *only* manufacturer of the closed loop H-bar.

After nearly a year of searching for a cheaper alternative I finally just bit the bullet and ordered the bar from Jones. It would have been better if I had ordered it sooner instead of holding out in hopes of finding an alternative manufacturer, I really got dinged by exchange rates for waiting.

Comment: Actually that's not true, the Chinese are now making rip-off copies of this: https://imgur.com/a/IjkPThM

Comment: @DmitriNesteruk If you have a lead on an alternative, then put it in an answer to this question and link us to where you can buy them.

Answer (score 1):

Titec used to make a cheaper aluminum version, but it's been discontinued. You can probably still find them on eBay.

Comment: From what I can tell, Titec never made h-bars with a *closed* loop, it looks like they only ever made the cut H-bars. There's nothing on ebay.

Comment: @ShemSeger I believe you are correct there.

Answer (score 1):

There are some alternative manufacturers of relatively similar handlebars, even though some of them are even more expensive and thus not the answer the OP wants, some of them are cheaper.

(I give you only the names because links are not allowed by BSE).

[Humpert Boomerang Handlebars - 25.4 mm Clamp](http://www.humpert.com/en/bikeparts/marke/produktart/einsatzbereich/produkt/?marke=ergotec&produktart=1&einsatzbereich=1&produkt=129)

Halo Bar, found at [TiCycles](http://ticycles.com/TCF/hardware.html).

This unluckyly discontinued [OEM titanium Halo Handlebar 22.2](http://www.aliexpress.com/item/OEM-titanium-Halo-Handlebar-22-2-lifetime-warranty-custom/1850836248.html) that looks the same as the previous one.

I tried to search alternative names with no luck. Next best thing I can recomend that may give you similar hand positions are:

- Moustache Bar
- Butterfly Bar

If what you actually need is more space for accesories you can use one on this:

[Problem Solvers handlebar accesory mount](http://problemsolversbike.com/products/handlebar_accessory_mount)

This is the only comercially available product that I can mention, but I'm sure many others exist.

Depending on the type of accesories you need to mount you may be able to fashion DIY versions of this. Cyclocomputers, small lights, cellphone holders and similar are subjected to very small load, and can be perfectly mounted, for example on **PVC tubbing**, wich is very easy to paint black with spray paint to disguise the DIY factor.

PVC is very easy to work with, Can be cut and sanded with the same simple tools used for basic woodworking, and the 90 and 45 deg. elbows available are great for creating odd shapes.

Another source for DIY options is a hardware store. If you search google images for "**conduit brackets**" you'll see a lot of types of brackets used to hold pipes in place. Being a little creative and finding scrap pieces of tubing of the right diameter is all the other needed thing. You can, for example, attach a piece of tubbing parallel to the handlebar using clamps like these:

[image]

You can use **strips of old inner tube** to protect the handlebar from scratches, since these brakets are not very polished.

If you want to paint them, matt black anti corrosive spray paint gives a very good finish that kind-of resembles anodized black. Just use sandpaper to polish the brackets, wash them with kitchen soap to remove any grease and let dry before painting.

These brackets, properly combined can be firm enough to install bottle holders or heavier lights.

An advantage of these is that they are widely available, wich is an advantage when you mention touring since something may break while far from a specialized stores, but even small town hardware stores should carry pipe brackets.

(For example my commuting headlight is a tubular-shaped flashlight/torch held in place by means of two interlaced hose clamps. The clamps are looped one through the other in conventional-chain-like fashion. A strip from inner tube protects the handlebar and another protects the flashlight. The grip is so solid that I can perform some stunts or ride fast rocky descents and the light won't move at all).

Since many accesories come with adjustable mounting brackets, you have yet another option that is using handlebar extensions to gain more room to mount accesories. If your handlebar are the thin diameter (25.4 dia) you can mount the extensions very close to the center of the bar.

Comment: Others may find this handy, but It's not the answer I'm looking for. I'll may end up buying accessory mounts anyways, but the real appeal to the H-bar is it's ergonomic sweep. The H-bar Loop is a perk, and the fact that it's a single unit means it's lighter and stronger.

Comment: @ShemSeger: I see your point. Is it possible in your location to have it custom made in a metal-working shop? I don't think it's going to be that expensive. Maybe starting with a "moustache" handlebar, wich should have the handling geometry you look for (hand angled backwards and behind the stem clamping point) and getting the "loop" from a sacrificial second handlebar.

Comment: I actually have a moustache bar *and* a butterfly bar already. It's true I could just weld a flatbar into my moustache as a cross section, but welding aluminum is not cheap, it would actually be cheaper to spend the $120 on a Jones bar. (Even if I were to do it myself, Al welding rods alone are ~$40 each, and welding aluminum is tricky because it only works when the alloys have been heated to the right temperature.)

Comment: Links are not allowed?

Answer (score 1):

It appears that on-one are doing a 'Geoff' bar available in the UK through Planet X at a very reasonable 25 quid.